# Devbridge Autocomplete serviceUrl not showing results

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete

Devbridge Autocomplete works with "lookup" but when I switch to serviceUrl it doesn't show the results. There are no errors and the json validates.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="currency" class="biginput" id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off">
```

JS:

```
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
     //lookup: currencies,
     serviceUrl: "http://localhost/agfg1Member/handlers/ACKeyword.ashx",
     onSelect: function (suggestion) {
              var thehtml = '<strong>Currency Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.value + ' <br> <strong>Symbol:</strong> ' + suggestion.data;
              $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
     },
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     minChars: 2 });
```

Example of json from c# ashx handler

```
({"suggestions":[{"value":"Tuggerah","data":{"category":"Suburb","id":"3371","parentCat":"3"}},{"value":"Tuggeranong","data":{"category":"Suburb","id":"3372","parentCat":"80"}},{"value":"Tugun","data":{"category":"Suburb","id":"3373","parentCat":"33"}}]})
```

The brackets make it jsonp. This is JSONLINT validated without the brackets:

```
{
"suggestions": [
    {
        "value": "Tuggerah",
        "data": {
            "category": "Suburb",
            "id": "3371",
            "parentCat": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "value": "Tuggeranong",
        "data": {
            "category": "Suburb",
            "id": "3372",
            "parentCat": "80"
        }
    },
    {
        "value": "Tugun",
        "data": {
            "category": "Suburb",
            "id": "3373",
            "parentCat": "33"
        }
    }
]}
```

And the ashx file outputs         context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

I tried adding "jsonp: 'cb'" to the source code, still nothing.

Uses jquery.1.9.1
Also, when stepping through the javascript, the var response remains undefined. I don't know what this means, but it doesn't sound good, hey?

Comment: Is "Devbridge Autocomplete" different from jquery UI autocomplete https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ ?

Comment: Yes it is @guest271314. I couldn't tag that though. https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: Can not utilize `lookup: function (query, done) {` pattern ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?